# Can not update to Catalina

Tags: catalina, software-update

I have macOS 10.14.6 and can not upgrade to Catalina on 2016 MacBook Pro.  The message says I am already up to date.

Comment: How are you trying to upgrade and where are you getting the message from?

Comment: Are you running Catalina beta by any chance?